# Proof of A Property of Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am proving the following property of Lebesgue Integral:

> Let $(E,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measurable space. If $a\le f(x)\le b$ for $x\in E$, and $\mu(E)\lt \infty$, then $$a\mu(E)\le \int_E f\ d\mu\le b\mu(E).$$

The following was what I tried:

First assume that $f(x)\le0$ for some $x\in E$ and $f(x)\ge0$ for some $x\in E$, and then $b\ge 0$ and $a\le 0$. 
Let $f=f^+-f^-$, and then $f^+ \le b$ and $f^- \le -a$. 
Let $s$ be the simple function such that $$0\le s \le f^+ \le b$$ and$$0\le s \le f^- \le -a.$$Then, we have: $$0\le \int_E f^+\ d\mu =\sup_{0\le s\le f}\int_Es d\mu \le b\cdot\mu(E)$$and $$0\le \int_E f^-\ d\mu =\sup_{0\le s\le f}\int_Es d\mu \le -a\cdot\mu(E).$$ Since by the definition, we have $$\int_E f\ d \mu=\int_E f^+\ d \mu-\int_E f^-\ d \mu. $$
Then $$\int_E f\ d \mu=\int_E f^+\ d \mu-\int_E f^-\ d \mu \le \int_E f^+\ d \mu \le b\cdot\mu(E)$$ and $$\int_E f\ d \mu=\int_E f^+\ d \mu-\int_E f^-\ d \mu \ge -\int_E f^-\ d \mu \ge a\cdot\mu(E). $$Then the desired result follows. 

The cases where $f$ is strictly negative or strictly positive can be proved separately.

Does this proof make sense? Is there any simpler way to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on context. Once you have established enough theory, the proof is utterly trivial. Something like your proof is only needed in the early stages of developing the theory. And since there are many ways to do this, it is hard to say if there is a better way without knowing what text you're following, and where you are in it.

Comment: Like Harald said, if $f$ is measurable, normally its
$$ \int_E f d\mu \geq \int_E a\,d\mu = a\mu(E)
$$
and similar for $\leq$, but Im not sure if you have already shown that the Lebesgue integral is monotone.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to first recall the definition of an integral on a subset of a measure space. Say $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space. If $E\subseteq X$ and $E\in\mathcal{M}$ is a measurable set, then we define:

> $\int_{E}f\ d\mu=\int_{X} \chi_{E}(x)\cdot f(x)\ d\mu.$

Now, we need one basic property of the Lebesgue integral. Namely, if we have two functions $p(x),q(x):X\to \mathbb{R}$ and $p(x)\le q(x)$ a.e., then

> $\int p(x)\ d\mu\le \int q(x)\ d\mu$ (1)

It is good practice for you to prove this straight from the definitions (it follows from the fact that every simple function dominated by $p(x)$ is dominated from $q(x))$. Now, the statement that $f(x)\le a$ on $E$ is precisely the statement that $\chi_{E}(x)\cdot f(x)\le a\chi_{E}(x)$ a.e., and likewise the statment $b\le f(x)$ on $E$ is precisely the statement that $\chi_{E}(x)\cdot f(x)\ge b\chi_{E}(x)$ a.e. (work this part out!). Consequently, by $(1)$, we have that

> $b\mu(E)=\int b\chi_{E}(x)\ d\mu\le\int \chi_{E}(x)\cdot f(x)\ d\mu\le \int \chi_{E}(x)\cdot a \ d\mu=a\mu(E)$

Comment: I think I switched your roles of $a$ and $b$, but hopefully this is clear enough.